# Adding tooltip to css printfile table

Tags: php, css, tooltip

I want to print a table from a file, so that it is simple for non-geeky cohorts to easily update the table without my help. The problem is that I want the top line of the table to print with different tooltips for each column. How do I do this in php or is there a better way?

`echo "<tr><th>Date Available From (TOOLTIP) </th><th> Photo (TOOLTIP)</th><th> Age (TOOLTIP)</th><th> Breed (TOOLTIP)</th>`

```
<?php 
$tdcount = 1; $numtd = 13; // number of cells per row 
print "<table class='hovertable'>";
print "<tr><th colspan=13><h1>AVAILABLE HORSES</h1></th></tr>";
       echo "<tr><th>Date Available From  </th><th>Photo</th><th>Age</th><th>Breed</th><th>Gender</th><th>Height</th><th>Colour</th><th>Price</th><th>Bred</th><th>Training</th><th>Known soundess illness injuries</th><th>Description</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

        $f = fopen("available.txt", "r") or die("can't open file"); 
        while (!feof($f)) { 
        $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 
    $row = current ( $arrM ); 
    if ($tdcount == 1) 
    print "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#f9ce68';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">"; print "<td>$row </td>"; 
        if ($tdcount == $numtd) { 
            print "</tr>"; 
            $tdcount = 1; 
        } else { 
            $tdcount++; 
        } 
        } 
        if ($tdcount!= 1) { 
            while ($tdcount <= $numtd) { 
                print "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; $tdcount++; 
            } print "</tr>"; 
        } 
        print "</table>"; 
    ?>
```

Fixed it.

Pulled the table and first th lines out of the php, they didn't need to be in there and now I have no problems putting int he tool tip on images in the th like I wanted.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions! :)

Comment: Do you have any code that we can reference as to what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: Can you not just use the `title` attribute: `<tr><th title="tooltip">...</th>...`?

Comment: It wasn't working for me daiscog, unsure why! will try again

Comment: You say to "update the table without my help", so you're looking for a type of script that others can update/change, or are you just asking for `styling` help?

Comment: A table others can update/change easily by just editing the text file. People who don't code AT all.

Comment: no title attributes (with either img or a href) are working for me, I'm still fairly new to php, this maybe a simple mistake.

Comment: by the looks of what your `available.txt` file may be, you have (13x) entries on a new line, am I right? Meaning, they're one under each other.

Comment: @VanessaDurand Check out the following link, it's what I used for an old site I managed while using a flatfile database, very useful. Link: http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/flatfile-database-manager.php - you can then limit access to your file via `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yes Fred it looks like this:
  
25/04/13<br>#15  
<img src="..."  
~1 year old  
arabian  
mare  
unknown, foal  
  
....  
With each on a different line, don't know how to fix my comment to do that :) 
Will look into the flatfile, tx.

Comment: @VanessaDurand Arabian, cool, used to ride those myself. As for the database script I included above, might be your best bet and can easily be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: @daiscog She could, however you would either have to `escape` the double-quotes `\"` or use single quotes. Otherwise, it'd throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

**To partially answer your question, you can use:**
`<th title='Date Available From'>Date Available From</th>`, tested in Firefox and IE7 only.

As for your question regarding people updating the fields themselves, you'll have to look into a database; either flatfile or SQL.

All titles have been added to your top line in your table:

```
<?php

$tdcount = 1; $numtd = 13; // number of cells per row 
print "<table class='hovertable'>";
print "<tr><th colspan=13><h1>AVAILABLE HORSES</h1></th></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th title='Date Available From'>Date Available From  </th><th title='Photo'>Photo</th><th title='Age'>Age</th><th title='Breed'>Breed</th><th title='Gender'>Gender</th><th title='Height'>Height</th><th title='Colour'>Colour</th><th title='Price'>Price</th><th title='Bred'>Bred</th><th title='Training'>Training</th><th title='Known soundess illness injuries'>Known soundess illness injuries</th><th title='Description'>Description</th><th title='Status'>Status</th></tr>";

    $f = fopen("available.txt", "r") or die("can't open file"); 
    while (!feof($f)) { 
    $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 
$row = current ( $arrM ); 
if ($tdcount == 1) 
print "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#f9ce68';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">"; print "<td>$row </td>"; 
    if ($tdcount == $numtd) { 
        print "</tr>"; 
        $tdcount = 1; 
    } else { 
        $tdcount++; 
    } 
    } 
    if ($tdcount!= 1) { 
        while ($tdcount <= $numtd) { 
            print "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; $tdcount++; 
        } print "</tr>"; 
    } 
    print "</table>"; 
?>
```